# How to use Docker API to get the Mac Address of the container - from within the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to get the Mac address of a running Docker container using Docker API from within the same container. I do not want to use any other mechanism but only the Docker API for this purpose. Can anyone help?

Comment: Note that the requirement to use the docket api for this means the container has full root access on the host, removing any security benefits of running commands inside a container.